# Calling Realm.close() outside of Activity

Tags: android, realm

I would like to move all Realm operations (read/write) from Activities/Fragments (as implemented in most examples) to a separate class / layer of classes.

My question is when and where should I call Realm.getInstance() and Realm.close() if not used directly in Activity/Fragment? what would be a good pattern?

Let's assume operations can all be performed in the UI thread and don't need to be performed in AsyncTasks.

Thanks

Comment: It really depends on what kind of architecture you have, can you describe what you are trying? Are you already doing something like MVP or MVC? But usually you need some awareness of the Android lifecycle either way to control other resources as well.

Comment: Thanks Christian. I'm planning to use dependency injection (Dagger) and event bus (Otto) to facilitate managing DB operations outside of the activities and notifying the activities that data has been updated so UI can be refreshed.

Comment: And are you suggesting that I should always notify the class which performs the Realm operations that an activity has been created/destroyed so getInstance() and close() can be called?

Comment: Yes, or at least when there are no longer any open activities. This can eg. be done by having a counter incrementing during onStart and decrementing during onStop.

Answer (score 0):

You can stick it in a helper class like this:

```
public class RealmHelper {

  private static RealmHelper realmHelper;
  private static Realm realm;

  public static RealmHelper getInstance(Context context) {
    realm = Realm.getInstance(context);
    if(realmHelper == null) {
        realmHelper = new RealmHelper();
    }
    return realmHelper;
  }

  private RealmHelper() {
  }

  public void saveMy(MyModel my) {
    realm.beginTransaction();
    realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(my);
    realm.commitTransaction();
  }
  ...
```

And then call it when you need it:

```
...
RealmHelper realmHelper = RealmHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
realmHelper.saveMy(my);
...
```

Comment: Thanks. But this is no longer relevant as we can now use Realm.getDefaultInstance() to get a default realm instance without passing in the context. Realm.getInstance(context) will also be deprecated in version 0.88.0.

Comment: Yes, but you still need to stick in RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context).build(); with Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);